# Is there a more efficient way to do scrabble search with grep?

Tags: regex, unix, grep, command, words

I am solving the following problem in unix

20. Suppose you are playing Scrabble. You have the following seven letters in your rack – E A F N A S M. These are letters you can use to make a word, you can use any number of them in your word, but must use at least one. You are trying to place a word on a spot on the board where there is already a word: ARE.

    Your goal is to find a word that will attach to the word ARE with the letters you have in your rack. While usually your letters may be placed before or after the ARE to make a new word, in this case ARE is at the edge of the board, so your word must end in ARE. Your goal is to find all possible words that meet these criteria in the /usr/dict/words using grep.

The command I came up with is really inefficient but works.

```
grep “^[eafnasm][eafnasm]*are$” /usr/dict/words |
grep -v “a.*a.*a.*a” |
grep -v “e.*e.*e” |
grep -v “f.*f” |
grep -v “n.*n” |
grep -v “s.*s” |
grep -v “m.*m” |
grep -v “^...........”
```

Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: Don't use curly quotes in shell scripts.

Comment: The 2nd `a` in each character class is redundant.  You could instead write the first regexp as `^[eafnsm]\+are$`.

Comment: Are you sure you must continue the word ARE or you must cross it?

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte: It says "your word must end in ARE".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to speed things up would be:

```
grep -E '^[aefmns]{1,7}are$' /usr/dict/words |
grep -Ev 'a.*a.*a.*a|e.*e.*e|f.*f|n.*n|s.*s|m.*m'
```

It cuts down the number of processes looking at the data.  I removed the second A from the initial character class since it is redundant, but the repetition represents a negligible cost.  Using the `{1,7}` qualifier in the first pattern means there's no need to filter overlong names in the second.

Note that the first search doesn't allow multiple R's through.  It's a specialization for this specific combination of letters-in-hand plus word-on-board.  If the hand held an R (instead of, say, the second A), then it would be necessary to filter more than 2 R's out of the results (two because under this scenario, there is one R in hand and one in the word on the board), and the multiple-A filter would have to change too.

Note that the changes here are just minor tweaks to the original 8 `grep` commands being run.  Since the solution is required to use `grep` (ruling out Perl, Python, Awk, ...), you probably can't get to fewer than two commands, one 'positive' `grep` to select possibilities, and one 'negative' `grep` to eliminate impossibilities.  With custom tooling (specialized programs written in C or C++ or something similar), you could probably do better.

If your version of `grep` supports PCRE (Perl-compatible regular expressions), you might be able to do it 'all in one'.  I'm fairly sure it would be less readable and comprehensible, and while it might perform a little better (less I/O because there's no pipe), the performance improvement would have to be measured.  Sometimes, simpler is better.

Comment: I prefer `grep -Ev '(a.*a.*a|e.*e|f.*f|m.*m|n.*n|s.*s).*are$'` since it makes it clearer how many of each letter is too many.

Comment: How about the word `fanfare`?

Comment: @AdamSpiers: Yes, but with this way the string need to be tested until the end.

Comment: @l'L'l -- Tarantara...  What about the word FANFARE?  It contains 2 letters F and is therefore excluded by the second `grep` -- the negative `grep`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Ah okay, I didn't realize it was one letter only — nice solution :)

Comment: Not sure that a backtracking engine will be more efficient for this task, even if indeed you can write all in one pattern.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte: try the revised text at the end.  You could easily be right that the RE would be so horrendous that the cost outweighs the benefit -- even assuming it can be done 'all in one'.

Comment: I follow your changes.

Comment: Would this work the same `grep -Ev '([a]{3}|[e]{2}|[fmns]).*\1'`?

Comment: @l'L'l: No, because that requires the A's to be adjacent whereas the 'a.*a.*a.*a' allows them to A's to be non-contiguous.

Comment: Interesting; I must not fully understand it; if I take `grep -E '^[isefmph]{1,12}ere$' /usr/dict/words` and pipe `grep -Ev '(s.*){3}s'` or `grep -Ev '([s]{3}).*\1'` to it I get the same exact results, and `semisphere` shows up in both. I think maybe it's time for me to learn how this `scrabble` game works.

Comment: Scrabble is a bit like a crossword puzzle. You have some letters on the board (except when you play first), and each other move must place letters from the hand on the board to make a word (and no non-words) by adding to  either or both ends of an existing word, or using one of the letters in an existing word as one of the letters in your new word.  You have 7 letters in a hand until the end (when they're running out). Letters have different scores (1-10); squares have different scores (normal, double or triple letter score, double or triple word); and blanks are wild-cards but score zilch.

Comment: @l'L'l: Regarding your regexes; SEMISPHERE should be allowed through by both as it contains just 2 S's but the first regex eliminates lines (words) with 4 S's and the second eliminates lines with SSS followed by anything and another SSS.  The `-v` puts a spanner in the works; it negates the logic.